# Show only user specific team activities

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Lets say

User A belongs to  Team X and Team Y

User B belong to Team X

User C belongs to Team X

I want to create a view to display only activities owned by users belonging to Team X and not belonging to both Team X&Y. That result set should only display activities belonging to User B&C.

I created a view but it shows activities of user A as well.

[Advance Find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeFy5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want one of these 'equals current user...' options.

[image]

Or perhaps simply this - you can enter multiple users.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also have to keep in mind Security roles and how they impact your views.  If you are a SysAdmin, your views will not be filtered at all by ownership - only the criteria you put into the view.  If you have a view where "Owner = Team A", then SysAdmin would see all those records where Owner = Team A.  If you have a less-permissed user (say, they only have USER LEVEL read on the entity), and the view is "Owner =Team A"  - they'd only see records in that view if they belonged to Team A.

It is important to know that User ownership is a mirror of Team ownership.  So, User level read actually lets me see ALL records that I own or MY TEAMS own, that satisfy your filter criteria.

Above answer *should* work - I would use "Equals Current User or User's Teams" but again, depends on exactly what you are trying to do and how everything is setup in CRM